# How do I get a simple scatter plot of a dataframe (preferrably with seaborn)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, seaborn

I'm trying to scatter plot the following dataframe:

```
mydf = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 
                 'y':[9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1], 
                 'z':np.random.randint(0,9, 9)},
                index=["12:00", "1:00", "2:00", "3:00", "4:00", 
                       "5:00", "6:00", "7:00", "8:00"])



        x   y   z
 12:00  1   9   1
  1:00  2   8   1
  2:00  3   7   7
  3:00  4   6   7
  4:00  5   5   4
  5:00  6   4   2
  6:00  7   3   2
  7:00  8   2   8
  8:00  9   1   8
```

I would like to see the times "12:00, 1:00, ..." as the x-axis and `x,y,z` columns on the y-axis.

When I try to plot with pandas via `mydf.plot(kind="scatter")`, I get the error `ValueError: scatter requires and x and y column`. Do I have to break down my dataframe into appropriate parameters? What I would really like to do is get this scatter plotted with seaborn.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just running

```
mydf.plot(style=".")
```

works fine for me:

[image: example scatterplot as result of the code above]

Comment: Thanks, this is what I want. But I still don't see how I can get this with seaborn.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean "with seaborn". Pandas uses matplotlib to plot and thus will inherit the seaborn styling for all its plots, not any different from using matplotlib directly.

Comment: Ah, I was confused about this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Seaborn is actually built around `pandas.DataFrame`s. However, your [data frame needs to be "tidy"](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/axis_grids.html):

1. Each variable forms a column.
2. Each observation forms a row.
3. Each type of observational unit forms a table.

Since you want to plot x, y, and z on the same plot, it seems like they are actually *different observations*. Thus, you really have three variables: time, value, and the letter used.

The ["tidy" standard comes from Hadly Wickham, who implemented it in the tidyr package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html).

First, I convert the index to a Datetime:

```
mydf.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(mydf.index)
```

Then we do the conversion to tidy data:

```
pivoted = mydf.unstack().reset_index()
```

and rename the columns

```
pivoted = pivoted.rename(columns={"level_0": "letter", "level_1": "time", 0: "value"})
```

Now, this is what our data looks like:

```
  letter                time  value
0      x 2019-03-13 12:00:00      1
1      x 2019-03-13 01:00:00      2
2      x 2019-03-13 02:00:00      3
3      x 2019-03-13 03:00:00      4
4      x 2019-03-13 04:00:00      5
```

Unfortunately, seaborn doesn't play with DateTimes that well, so you can just extract the hour as an integer:

```
pivoted["hour"] = pivoted["time"].dt.hour
```

With a data frame in this form, seaborn takes in the data easily:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()

sns.scatterplot(data=pivoted, x="hour", y="value", hue="letter")
```

Outputs:

[image: Plot of data]